# web3.py - wait for callbacks

Tags: python, web3.py

I am trying to figure out how to use Web3 filters, as I need to sync a backend with my blockchain.

Ideally, I want a function to trigger every time a transaction takes place.

I have it working fine based on the examples [here](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/filters.html), however this only works in the interactive shell. If run in a Python script, it just executes synchronously and terminates immediately. Here is the code:

```
import sys

from web3 import Web3, IPCProvider

from web3.utils.filters import TransactionFilter

w3 = Web3(IPCProvider('/x/x/x/ethereum/geth.ipc'))

def new_transaction_callback(transaction_hash):
    sys.stdout.write("New Block: {0}".format(transaction_hash))

new_transaction_filter = w3.eth.filter('pending')
new_transaction_filter.watch(new_transaction_callback)
```

What is the correct way to wait indefinitely, and execute the callback whenever a transaction takes place?

Comment: FYI, anything in `web3.utils.*` is not meant as a public API, and could change at any time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If run in a Python script, it just executes synchronously and terminates immediately.

There are a variety of ways to keep your runtime alive after your script completes. A couple options are:

- Invoke your script with `python -i my_script.py`
- Append `while True: time.sleep(10)` to your script and just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to exit
- many more...